# How to enable the menus and widgets in appearance in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a new wordpress themes. In that the menus and widgets options are not visible in the dashboard in wordpress.Can anyone tell y it is like that and how to enable it ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this snippet on your active theme's `functions.php`

```
function mytheme_register_nav_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'your-text-domain' )
    )); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_register_nav_menus' );

function mytheme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Appears on posts and pages except the optional Front Page template, which has its own widgets', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mytheme_widgets_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sark 's answer, pointing out that your theme must set up a menu and a sidebar to activate those admin screens, your WP user must have the edit_theme_options capability. If you can already see the Themes menu then they do.